# Outlook Anywhere - Remote Wipe?

Tags: security, exchange-2007, outlook

Is it possible to remotely wipe an Outlook 2007 client that is using Outlook anywhere, similar to how you can remotely wipe an exchange connected mobile device?

Comment: What is an "Exchange Connected Mobile Device"?  We have Windows Mobile 5 handhelds using ActiveSync on Exch 2003.  Can I somehow wipe them remotely?

Comment: Yes. It's a lot more straightforward with Exchange 2007, but you can do it with Exchange 2003, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.

The only thing that could achieve a similar effect is emptying the Exchange mailbox; on the first synchronization, the client will delete its local cache.

Answer (score 0):

Worked perfectly, nice job! I just disconnected his existing mailbox (so I could access it later), re-created a new empty mailbox and the firt time the terminated employee logged in it wiped out his cached mailbox.

Comment: This is really more of a comment then an answer...